# Panning the display area in WPF

Tags: wpf

The application will have a menu strip on top and the rest will display lines and shapes. I want to be able to drag and pan the main display area by clicking it and dragging it in any direction.

I am currently drawing items using pixel values (for example a line drawn from (1042,54)to(1240,104). But I think a monitor with a smaller resolution will not be able to display that object. That is why I want to be able to pan the display area.

The lines and shapes are currently being drawn on a gird that I placed inside the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the canvas inside a [`ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx) then if the canvas is larger than the application window it will be displayed with scroll bars.

You can then address points on the canvas with values relative to the canvas rather than the screen.

Comment: Let me give this a try, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, the scrolling part is working well. But the MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown event does not trigger. I have to click the mouse button several times before it triggers. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Figured it out. Had to set Background="Transparent"